# how to return 2D string array/vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have function like this

```
typedef vector<vector<string> > vecArray;
vecArray dul();

vecArray dul() {
    vecArray arr = {
                    { "a", "b", "c" },
                    { "a", "b", "c" },
                    { "a", "v", "d" }
                    };
    return arr;
}
```

i want to return look like bellow string in C++ function

```
{
{"ffsff","aaaasda","ddaddd"},
{"sfsasda","sdadsfd","asasaad"},
{"adacv","fasfaa","asa","aba"}
}
```

Comment: That should work. What's wrong with it? That only works in C++11, where an initializer list can be an argument, mind you.

Comment: i got  "in C++98 'arr' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'" error

Comment: Yes, you need C++11 to use that syntax. That's because in C++11, the vector now can -and does- provide a constructor taking an initializer list. More info on that here: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list. You can, however, make a 2D array of strings and use that to construct your vector.

Comment: i'm new to C++. i thought C++11 and C++98 may be different compiler. is that correct? plz suggest how to run under in C++98

Comment: You may need an updated compiler for the features to be supported. You also need the `-std=c++0x` flag set in your compiler options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't construct a vector with an initializer list, as that feature is only available in C++11. You can, with ease though, construct the vector using a 2D array.

```
vecArray dul() {
    string arrTemp [3][3] = //create 2D array of strings
        {
            { "a", "b", "c" },
            { "a", "b", "c" },
            { "a", "v", "d" }
        };

    vecArray arr; //here's our vector

    //for 3 arrays, push each onto back of vector using the iterator constructor
    for (vecArray::size_type i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
        arr.push_back (vector<string> (arrTemp [i], arrTemp [i] + 3));

    return arr;
}
```